# Request header field authorization

Tags: vue.js, axios, cors

I am trying to create "UUID" form [this](https://www.uuidtools.com/api/generate/v1) Api call
I am using **axios** and **vue.js**. Here's my source code.

```js
generateUUID() {
  // console.log("call generate uuid");
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',  
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
  
  axios.get('https://www.uuidtools.com/api/generate/v1', {
    headers: headers
  }).then(response => console.log(response))        
},
```

But unfortunately I am getting

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.uuidtools.com/api/generate/v1' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried searching google and followed many answers already to that question but got nothing.

Comment: It should work without `headers` option, remove it.

Comment: @Radeanu its not working

Answer (score 0):

### Problem(s)

1. [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) and [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) are [*response* headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header), not [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header). Specifying them in a request is more than useless; it's actually counterproductive, here.
2. Why would you specify a content type for a `GET` request? `GET` requests are [not supposed to have a body](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1):

   > A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
   > sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
   > implementations to reject the request.
3. According to my tests, the resource that you're requesting (`https://www.uuidtools.com/api/generate/v1`) appears to be CORS-aware but expects only [*simple* requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests), not [*preflight* requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests). And because your request contains headers that are not [CORS-safelisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_request_header), it gets preflighted by your browser, and the preflight access-control check fails.

### Solution

Just send a *simple* `GET` request (without adding any headers):

```js
fetch('https://www.uuidtools.com/api/generate/v1')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(arr => arr[0])
  .then(console.log)
```

#### Console output

No CORS error, then:

[image: console]]